# UWP IoT RPi3 connection to MediaServer (DLNA) can't list folders

Tags: c#, uwp, iot, directory, nas

I have a RPi3 running on Core IoT and i would like to have access to a Synology NAS to retrieve sound files. When i run the app on my local machine (Win10, PC), all is fine, i can list the Folders and files, but when i try the same app on my RPi, i simply get a "The system cannot find the file specified" error.

What i did so far:

- Checked capapbilities (seem to be OK as i have Access from PC)
- getting IPs from Network devices like NAS, Denon Heos Speakers, etc, 
  so i have a working DeviceWatcher
- i can pair the NAS to the System and read out properties

my Question now is: How can i read the Folders on the NAS from a RPi with core IoT? Do i Need to pair (AEP, device pairing) the NAS to the RPi, and if yes, what do i need to do then? How can i pass the credentials to log in to the NAS?

i'm reading MS articles since days without success and i'm really stuck.

Comment: Could you please provide the code snippet about how to access NAS?

Comment: Hi, as mentioned, the Code works on PC but not on RPi core IoT. Furthermore, this is my Setup:
- PC with Win10 (192.168.0.zzz)
- Rpi with core IoT (192.168.0.yyy)
- NAS with Synology, where all mp3 files are (192.168.0.xxx)

Now, i would like to connect to NAS from RPi to Play Music. Heres the Code to get the Folders:

StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"\\192.168.0.xxx\");

Folder remains null

Comment: Hi, @LPatera, have you tried to disable the firewall on your Respberry Pi? Via the command `netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off`.

Comment: Tried that, gives me still this error:

WinRT information: An item cannot be found at the specified path
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Hi, @LPatera Sorry for my late reply. I have involved somebody familiar with issue to check whether Windows IoT Core supports NFS protocol.